# Python Morse code error

Tags: python

The following is a decision tree I built to recognize Morse code numbers 0-9. However, python always give me syntax error when I test it. Could anyone help me to solve the problem? Thanks a lot!

```
Morse=['p0',{1:['p1':{2:1,1:['p2':{2:2,1:['p3':{2:3,1:['p4':{2:4,1:5}]}]}]}], {2:['p1':{1:6,2:['p2':{2:7,1:['p3':{2:8,1:['p4':{2:9,1:0}]}]}]}]}]
```

Comment: What is the syntax error?

Comment: Could you post some of your code? How are you trying to move through the tree and stuff?

Comment: i think maybe its the brackets. Did I put the brackets at the right place?

Comment: Don't try to shove all this on one line. You have 10 closing brackets and braces all right next to each other. It's horribly unreadable.

Comment: Why do you have colons in lists? `['p1':` is not valid Python syntax, no matter what comes next.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

```
Morse=['p0',{1:[{'p1':{2:1,1:[{'p2':{2:2,1:[{'p3':{2:3,1:[{'p4':{2:4,1:5}}]}}]}}]}}]}, {2:[{'p1':{1:6,2:[{'p2':{2:7,1:[{'p3':{2:8,1:[{'p4':{2:9,1:0}}]}}]}}]}}]}]
```

This might be wrong because you haven't exactly made it clear what you want... :) Your version had less curly braces, and you were assigning values like a map in square brackets (list format). Here was your error:

```
>>> Morse=['p0',{1:['p1':{2:1,1:['p2':{2:2,1:['p3':{2:3,1:['p4':{2:4,1:5}]}]}]}], {2:['p1':{1:6,2:['p2':{2:7,1:['p3':{2:8,1:['p4':{2:9,1:0}]}]}]}]}]
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    Morse=['p0',{1:['p1':{2:1,1:['p2':{2:2,1:['p3':{2:3,1:['p4':{2:4,1:5}]}]}]}], {2:['p1':{1:6,2:['p2':{2:7,1:['p3':{2:8,1:['p4':{2:9,1:0}]}]}]}]}]
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

You cannot make a list like this `['var':1]`, that is dict syntax. I coated this with curly brackets like this `[{'var':1}...]`, and I hope that's what you want!